# Sort list with data-attr and parent-child relationship

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list similar to this that I want to sort. It needs to sort by the data-order, with the parent first and children directly after.

parent with data-order 1

child with data-order 1

child with data-order 2

child with data-order 3

parent with data-order 2

child with data-order 1

child with data-order 2

Example:

```
<li class='category parent-category' data-order='1' data-categoryId='5' data-parentCategoryId=''>
   <a>Business Basics</a>
</li>

<li class='category parent-category' data-order='2' data-categoryId='2' data-parentCategoryId=''>
    <a>Back Office Basics</a>
</li>

<li class='category child-category' data-order='1' data-categoryId='3' data-parentCategoryId='5'>
    <a>Core Business</a>
</li>

<li class='category child-category' data-order='2' data-categoryId='4' data-parentCategoryId='5'>
    <a>Product</a>
</li>
```

Desired result:

```
<li class='category parent-category' data-order='1' data-categoryId='5' data-parentCategoryId=''>
   <a>Business Basics</a>
</li>

<li class='category child-category' data-order='1' data-categoryId='3' data-parentCategoryId='5'>
    <a>Core Business</a>
</li>

<li class='category child-category' data-order='2' data-categoryId='4' data-parentCategoryId='5'>
    <a>Product</a>
</li>

<li class='category parent-category' data-order='2' data-categoryId='2' data-parentCategoryId=''>
    <a>Back Office Basics</a>
</li>
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
  $(document).ready(function()
        {
            var orderedCats = $(".category").sort((a, b) =>
            {

                if ($(a).hasClass("parent-category")) {
                    var aCategory = $(a).data("categoryid");
                } else {
                    var aCategory = $(a).data("parentcategoryid");
                }

                if ($(a).hasClass("parent-category")) {
                    var aOrder = 0;
                    var order = $(a).data("order");
                } else {
                    var aOrder = $(a).data("order");

                }

                if ($(b).hasClass("parent-category")) {
                    var bCategory = $(b).data("categoryid");
                } else {
                    var bCategory = $(b).data("parentcategoryid");
                }

                if ($(b).hasClass("parent-category")) {
                    var bOrder = 0;
                } else {
                    var bOrder = $(b).data("order");
                }

                return (aCategory * 1000 + aOrder) - (bCategory * 1000 + bOrder);
            });

            $(".categories").html(orderedCats);
        });
```

My thought was to multiply the parents data-order by 1000, and if it's a child add its order id to the parents.

parents 1000, 2000, 3000, ...

children 1001, 1002, ... , 2001, 2002, ...

But I can't figure out how to relate the childs parentcategoryid attribute to the parents categoryid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a new data attribute, data-allorder, and set that before sorting so I only had to sort the one attribute. Here is how I solved this.

```
$('.category').each(function() {
    // if parent, set data-allorder to 1000 x data-order
    if ($(this).hasClass('parent-category')) {
        let parentOrder = parseInt($(this).attr('data-order'));
        $(this).attr('data-allorder', (parentOrder * 1000));
    }

    if ($(this).hasClass('child-category')) {
        // find data-allorder of parent, get child data-order, add, set child data-allorder
        let parentCategoryId = $(this).attr('data-parentcategoryid');
        let findParent = $('.categories').find('[data-categoryid="' + parentCategoryId + '"]');
        let parentAllOrder = parseInt($(findParent).attr('data-allorder'));
        let childOrder = parseInt($(this).attr('data-order'));
        $(this).attr('data-allorder', (parentAllOrder + childOrder));
    }
});

$(".categories li").sort(sort_li)
    .appendTo('.categories');

function sort_li(a, b) {
    return ($(b).data('allorder')) < ($(a).data('allorder')) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to multiply numbers, you just need to compare order field when both nodes are child or parent, and category against parentCategoryId if they are different.

Check this example - Instead of using html I used objects (so I can run it without jQuery), but replacing the properties accesors with `data('field')` should work. It is to give you an idea

```js
let array = [
  { parent: true, order: "1", categoryId: '5', text: 'business Basics' },
  { parent: true, order: "2", categoryId: '2', text: 'Back Office Basics' },
  { parent: false, order: "1", categoryId: '3', parentCategoryId: 5, text: 'Core Business' },
  { parent: false, order: "2", categoryId: '4', parentCategoryId: 5, text: 'Product' },
];
array.sort((a, b) => {
    // if both parent or both child, just compare the order.
    // here you would use hasClass('parent-category')
    if(a.parent === b.parent) {
      // compare order, using .data('order')
      let order1 = parseInt(a.order);
      let order2 = parseInt(b.order);
      return order1 - order2;
    }
    // here one of both is a child. Compare the categoryId of parent against parentCategory of child
    return a.parent ? parseInt(a.categoryId) - b.parentCategoryId : parseInt(b.categoryId) - a.parentCategoryId;
     
 });
console.log(array);
```